# how to catch-all for non-existent accounts in postfix

Tags: postfix-mta, account, catch-all

In postfix I want to do catch-all for only non-existent mails. Bu I have some accounts and they must work preoperly. If mail come for existent accounts they must deliver to own folders.

Comment: Please post your `postconf -n`, so that we can help with your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
there is my postconf;

alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 15728640
mydestination = website.net, localhost.website.net, localhost
myhostname = website.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/denied_recipients, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/blacklist_postfix
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap_senders.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = hash:/etc/postfix/blacklisted_domains
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/SSL/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/SSL/postfix.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/SSL/postfix.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = website.net website1.net website2.net website3.net website4.net website5.net website6.net
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```